# excel vba preserve original value if UDF formula fails

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In individual cells, I have an assigned formula that references a UDF:

```
=getValueFromWorkbook("OtherWorkbook", 10)
```

The `getValueFromWorkbook` UDF roughly does something like...

```
Function getValueFromWorkbook(workbookName As String, identifier As Integer) As Variant
  ' some magic is done to get the `worksheetName` and `cellRange`
  ' but for simplicity, we'll just stub them here...
  Dim worksheetName As String: worksheetName = "SomeWorkSheet"
  Dim cellRange As String: cellRange = "A1"
  getValueFromWorkbook = Workbooks("" & workbookName & ".xlsx").Worksheets(worksheetName).Range(cellRange).Value
End Function
```

This works great and as long as `OtherWorkbook.xlsx` is an open workbook, the cell gets the correct value and the world is happy.

Now, if I close the `OtherWorkbook.xlsx` workbook, things continue to work and the cell values are still reflected.

However, if I delete a row or perform some other action that causes Excel to recalculate all of the cell values, the UDF fails (because the referenced workbook is no longer open), resulting in a dreaded `#VALUE!`.

Ideally, I'd like this to preserve the original (stale) value rather than returning an error, but I haven't figured out a way to do this yet.

What I've tried...

```
Function getValueFromWorkbook(...) As Variant
  ...
  On Error Resume Next
    getValueFromWorkbook = ...
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    getValueFromWorkbook = Application.Caller.Value
  End If
End Function
```

But this results in a circular reference error:

> Cell references in the formula refer to the formula's result, creating a circular reference.

However, if I change `Application.Caller.Value` to `Application.Caller.Text`, this somewhat works, but it returns as text and I lose the original value formatting.

So, long story short, is there a way to preserve the original linked value rather than returning a garbage `#VALUE!`?

P.S. I'm pretty new to VBA so there might be something obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: Why not just copy the result from `getValueFromWorkbook("OtherWorkbook", 10)` into a cell somewhere in your current workbook and then base calculation on that? This way you know a value will always be there. Every time you successfully call this UDF, update the value into the "local" cell. Now when `OtherWorkbook.xlsx` is not available, you can fall back to the local cell.

Comment: Adding to Jasons suggestion, you could wrap your function in an iferror statement and call the otherworkbook function as the "value" portion, and use the copied data (as suggested by Jason) as the "If error" part.  So you get the most up to date value from the otherworkbook if its available, but if not, you get the last value that was read from it

Comment: Application.Caller.Value will always return a Circular reference because you are passing the cell to itself.  What value are you trying to show the user?  I would simply put a message in the "If Err.Number <> 0 Then" statement saying `getValueFromWorkbook = "Workbook not open"` or some other prompt to let a user know the workbook isn't open.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you're talking about now.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, that is a valid answer to the question.  You should post it.  imo.  That is what Excel is for, storing data, right?  I sometimes employ a hidden sheet with key variables that I want to store, such as year, and years running, booleans to tell if certain things have been done or not, so when I run other code, it can just check the state of the helper sheet and get values, set values, etc.

Comment: @PJRosenburg - I would have, but I didn't have time (at the time) to do a "proper" write-up for an answer. I'll type up one now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Application.Caller.Text` rather than `Application.Caller.Value` to return the original text of a cell.  The one drawback to this is that the cell's value, no matter the *type*, will be cast as a string.  Depending on other cells/formulas (i.e., if you're expecting the "OtherWorkbook" to return a number rather than a string) that reference the `Application.Caller` cell, you might have to update them with a `=VALUE()`.

This will work as long as you do not try to update the actual cell with the value in it.  As soon as you enter a cell, the `Application.Caller` turns into a circular reference and you will just get `0` back; you should be able to delete other rows though.

```
Function getValueFromWorkbook(...) As Variant
  Dim Org As String
  Org = Application.Caller.Text      

  ...
  On Error Resume Next
    getValueFromWorkbook = ...
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    getValueFromWorkbook = Org
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
' Globally available variable to cache the external value.
Public GlobalValue As Variant

Function getValueFromWorkbook(workbookName As String, identifier As Integer) As Variant
    ' some magic is done to get the `worksheetName` and `cellRange`
    ' but for simplicity, we'll just stub them here...
    Dim worksheetName As String: worksheetName = "SomeWorkSheet"
    Dim cellRange As String: cellRange = "A1"

    Dim returnValue As Variant

    ' Attempt to get from the external sheet.
    ' This will fail if it isn't available.
    On Error Resume Next
    returnValue = Workbooks(workbookName & ".xlsx").Worksheets(worksheetName).Range(cellRange).Value

    If Err = 0 Then
        ' No error, we retrieved the value from the external file.
        ' Set it locally for use when this value isn't available.
        GlobalValue = returnValue
    Else
        ' Error - the external sheet wasn't available.
        ' Use the local value.
        returnValue = GlobalValue
    End If

    ' Done with error trapping.
    On Error GoTo 0

    getValueFromWorkbook = returnValue

End Function
```

The idea is you cache the value locally and can use that as a fallback for when your `workbookName` isn't available.

Comment: A function called from a cell cannot write a value to another cell.

Comment: @Rory - Thanks for that. I've updated the answer to use a `GlobalValue` variable instead of writing it locally to a cell. The function now read/writes from here instead of an actual cell.

Comment: @Rory - can you provide any reference on the source for this "function called from a cell cannot write a value to another cell".  I was just trying to write a UDF function for generating a random number once, and making it non-mutable and would love to read more about the limitations you mention.

Comment: @CBRF23 For example, this MSKB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do it:

Suppose you put your User Defined Function **UDF** into cell **A1** and in certain conditions want it to keep the previous value without recalculating. Then in such cases make this function return any error value: `UDF = CVErr(xlErrNull)` and modify your **A1** formula in the following way: `=IFERROR(UDF(...); A1)`

*This likely will produce warnings of circular reference - you can get rid of it by enabling circular references in File -> Options -> Formulas and saving file with this setting.*